# How to use every row in a DataFrame to filter a query

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm having a problem I'm not being able to solve.

I've a Pandas' DataFrame like this:

```
    LastName FirstName Goals
0    Messi    Lionel    10

1   Donovan   Landon    7

2   Hazard     Eden     5
```

And I need to make a query for Teradata, to obtain data from another table, filtering the result by the LastName and FirstName of every people on the DataFrame, like this:

`"Select * from Table1 where (LastName= 'Messi' and FirstName='Lionel) or (LastName='Donovan' and FirstName='Landon') or (LastName='Hazard' and FirstName='Eden')"`

I've tried with some loop, but I'm not being able to do it, to take every row and add the or statement. Does anyone have an idea to solve it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your dataframe is moderately sized and the Teradata table is quite large, it would be more efficient to use the `teradataml` package `copy_to_sql` method to create a temporary (volatile) table in Teradata and then JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

We can usually do `merge`

```
cond=pd.DataFrame({'FirstName':['Lionel','Landon','Eden'], 'LastName':['Messi','Donovan','Hazard']})
df=df.merge(cond, how='inner')
```

Comment: First, thanks for your help ! But, I'm not sure that this can help me. I need to extract the data for a table in Teradata. Could I merge the DataFrame with those tables? 

I thought that it was only possible to make queries from them, so I was looking for a string that can be appended by row the filters I need to run the query with the pd.read_sql

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the values of multiple columns in a table vs. those in another table, you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE (LastName, FirstName) IN (
  SELECT lastname, firstname
  FROM <some_table>
)
```

I'm not sure how `DataFrame` works, but if you can access the `(lastname, firstname)` fields from your DataFrame result set in some flavor of `SQL`, try sticking that inside the `IN ()` construct.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0365/2)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by applying masks.

Assume given the df:

condition1: (LastName= 'Messi' and FirstName='Lionel')

```
cond1 = df['LastName'].eq('Messi') & df['FirstName'].eq('Lionel')
```

condition2: (LastName='Donovan' and FirstName='Landon')

```
cond2 = df['LastName'].eq('Donovan') & df['FirstName'].eq('Landon')
```

So as other names.

Then use loc to select:

```
df.loc[cond1 | cond2, :]
```

You can add as many conditions as you want. Hope this helps.